# How to integrate Google or Facebook login with my database?

Tags: security, authentication

I want to understand how to integrate auth of Google or Facebook with my database.
I have a login system with email and password, users table and messages table for that represent messages of users.

When someone registers, a new user with userID is created.
When a user login to the system with email and password he gets an auth token,
and for each action the user makes, like POST or GET requests for fetching or creating a new message, he sends the token he got and the system finds the userID by this token, and then finds his own messages.

Now I want to add Google and Facebook login, how should I do it now?
I can get from each of them a token. but the user isn't actually exists in my user table, so when I search the user by his token, I won't get anything, because he is not exists in the user table, and when I want to insert him to this table, I need to fill the password field there but I can't get it from google.

What should be the approach to do thing like this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When they first login, you can request their email from Facebook or google, the user will give your application access to see their email address.
At this point you could create a new user with that email and add a flag to say they came from facebook/google.
The rest works as normal, they would get a token from your application and so on.
In case they come back and login again, you don't need to register them as they are already in your database.

In case you need extra info from them, (more then just the info you can request from facebook/google) you could redirect them to a special form, for their first login.

Comment: So I should add the registered user from google to my users table?
without adding the password field? my password field is required for the simple login

Comment: that's correct, if you add them without password, they can't login the normal way and will always need to login through google, that's why there is a flag or something to indicate they used google login

Comment: but I think that I can't insert a record to my user table if a required filed(like password) is empty. I still want that filed to be required for the simple login. what should I do then?

Comment: Maybe at the flag to the password field then ? eg use `--facebook--` or `--google--` as their password. it is up to you really how you design the db / application.

Comment: making the password not required is a good way? 
what most people do about the password filed when creating the user table and the flag you mentioned?

Comment: As I said, the design is up to you, it is not because some way is done by most people that that is the right way for you. If you want to talk more about this, we can do this in a chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152020/questions-45707234
In the mean time, consider accepting the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152025/discussion-between-darkmukke-and-user3561607).